# How to use zxing core.jar into my own app

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I'm developping an app, and i need to store the product's barcode,so i need to read them.
I'v been reading other posts about what should i do to read a barcode without having to install BarcodeScanner.
I saw the post:

"The complete source code is available from the ZXing project. You want to build core.jar from core/ and put it in your Android lib/ folder to include the core decoder in your app. You do not want to include javase. You can look to the code in android/ as it is the source to Barcode Scanner, but as the authors we'd suggest you not just copy and paste it."

But,I am beginning at Android and don't know HOW exactly to do what it describes. Could someone be a little more specific how i do that?

Sorry if it is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the latest core-x.x.x.jar from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/
2. Switch to project folder view in Android Studio and copy the .jar into your `app/libs` folder[image: switch to project view]
3. Right click on the .jar and choose "Add As Library..."[image: Add As Library...]

This will automatically add the dependencies to your `build.gradle` so you can just start to use the library e.g. to generate and display a barcode as easy as in this example:

```
    import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
    import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
    import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
    import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
    ...
    ImageView qrImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrImageView);

    int width = 512;
    int height = 512;
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    try {
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode("Hello World", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,width,height);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                // Copy pixel-by-pixel
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        qrImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
```